Owner field not being set when creating data as a google signed in user in AWS Amplify react app
I have added google sign in to my app using AWS Amplify.
When I log in via google and create data, the owner field of the data being created in dynamoDB doesn't populate the owner field.
If I log in as a email/password user the owner field gets populated correctly.
I have thought about adding the owner field in the mutation but the default mutations for creating data don't include the owner field so I feel that might be the right path to take.
I have read the https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/ article but it doesn't extend to using the social signed on users to create data.
The only data missing is the owner ID. There was a github issue that was similar but I couldn't understand what the workaround was https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/93

Turns out my schema had
@model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: private }]) {.
When I removed the allow private everything worked nicely
